# What process can be used to compare elements from two separate lists?

Tags: java, list, compare

I need to first access and then compare elements from two separate lists and based on whichever element has the smaller value, remove the lesser element and assign it a position within a third list.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Is this merge part in merge sort?

Comment: Can you please provide more details about your problem? What does it mean by compare the elements i.e. if list1 = { 2,4 5} and list2= { 2, 6,8,9,12,56}, what result are you expecting after comparison?

Comment: @nhahtdh--can you elaborate a little bit more please?

Comment: @Yogendra Singh-I'm attempting to arrange the values from smallest integer to largest in ascending order.

Comment: @Jremy: I'm not suggesting solution. I'm asking whether this is the merge operation in merge sort, since it sounds like it is what you are doing.

Comment: @ nhahtdh-I'm just now reading a tutorial on merge sort...new to me as of this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just add the elements of both the list in a new list of one of the list and then sort it in ascending order e.g. below(pseudo code):

```
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(2,4,5);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(2,6,8,9,12,56);

    List<Integer> mergedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    mergedList.addAll(list1);
    mergedList.addAll(list2);
    Collections.sort(mergedList);
```

Now `mergedList` should have sorted elements.

Comment: --So the sort method is a method supplied by the Collections class?  What you propose makes sense to me, I was thinking about it from a different angle--trying to access one element at a time from each of the two lists and then comparing them before deciding where to put each one.

Comment: If you are trying to do it for your learning, you can do something as advised in my other answer, I am going to post for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your learning, find a **sample manual merge program** below:

```
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(2,4,5);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(2,6,8,9,12,56);

    List<Integer> mergedList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    mergedList1.add(list1.get(0));

    for(int indx = 1; indx< list1.size(); indx++){
        int valueToMerge = list1.get(indx);
        boolean merged = false;
        for(int indx1 = 0; indx1< mergedList1.size(); indx1++){
            if(mergedList1.get(indx1) > valueToMerge){
                //add the value in middle
                mergedList1.add(indx1, valueToMerge);
                merged = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!merged){
            //add the value in the end
            mergedList1.add(valueToMerge);
        }
    }

    for(int valueToMerge: list2){
        boolean merged = false;
        for(int indx1 = 0; indx1< mergedList1.size(); indx1++){
            if(mergedList1.get(indx1) > valueToMerge){
                //add the value in middle
                mergedList1.add(indx1, valueToMerge);
                merged = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!merged){
            //add the value in the end
            mergedList1.add(valueToMerge);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Or use a `SortedSet` and pop off the front item.

Comment: Agree. I understand there are better and multiple ways to achieve this. This second answer was for learning the internal algorithm in the way, user has requested. In first answer, I used Collections.sort() and it was simple too.